# The valueOf function doesn't work inside loop

Tags: java

Why valueOf function in my program doesn't work?

I get this message when I try to run it:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Temperature"
> at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
> at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
> at java.base/java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:512)
> at ac.uk.napier.set07110Coursework.Answer04.main(Answer04.java:34)

```
int d=0;

        for(int i=1; i<=12; i++) {
            for(int k=1; k<31; k++) {
                for (String element : myData) {
                    String[] cell = element.split(",");

                    if ((Double.valueOf(cell[9])<0.0) && (Integer.valueOf(cell[5])== i) && (Integer.valueOf(cell[6])== k)) {
                        d++;}
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Everything works besides

```
((Double.valueOf(cell[9])<0.0) && (Integer.valueOf(cell[5])== i) && (Integer.valueOf(cell[6])== k))
```

I need to convert the value from a string to int or double and neither of these conditions work. What's wrong?

Comment: `"Temperature"` can't be converted to an integer. What is so strange about that?

Comment: This would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger.  Add a breakpoint inside the inner most for loop, and inspect the value of the string `element`.  Check to make sure your splitting logic makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check using debuging or logging. According exceptions, you have `cell[9] = "Temperature"` instead of double value.

May be you need to check what values you have in "element" variable (I think you could miss that arrays start from 0 in java, so may be you should use `cell[8]` instead of `cell[9]`).

Comment: I've counted the indexes right, I want to change the temperature string to a double variable so I can compare the values

Comment: But how you are planning to convert "Temperature" value to double? It is impossible, using `Double.valueOf` this function can convert if string something like "12.3" or "-42.3", not for any text like "BlaBlaBla".

Comment: Ahh okay, I get it now, thank you so much for the help!